# Change adobe air installer

Tags: adobe

I made an installation file with adobe air (javascript, html via AIRSDK) , but it send an error message "This application cannot be installed because this installer has been mis-configured. Please contact the application author for assistance."
I do to  an air installer, 
change META-INF and icons in folder /icons, 
pack and install in windows 7.